# Passwordbox is always null in codebehind file

Tags: wpf

I have a username textbox and a passwordbox on wpf window and a drop down box.Based on selection of a specific item in the dropdown, I make the username and password field visible or invisible.

in dropdown selectedindex change event. I am setting the visibility of password box to hidden like below.
 **passwrd123.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;**

but I get objectreference error saying its null.
when I hover my mouse on passwrd123 I see it as null.could someone tell me what the issue is.

Comment: Could you please share some more code? Both XAML and the code behind.

Comment: share your xaml and if you are using mvvm the share your property too?

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectionChanged` event of your `ComboBox` can be executed when your WPF Window is loaded and not every UI Element in XAML is constructed yet - in this case, a quick solution would be to check for null when you access your `TextBox` or `PasswordBox`.

If this is not the case, please provide some code so that we are able to identify the problem more precisely.

Comment: But how come it works for other controls and not for password box alone?

Comment: I assume that your ComboBox is after the controls that you can access and before the ones that are still null when the first `SelectionChanged` event occurs. This is because XAML / BAML is parsed from top to bottom.